# Magento 2/Wordpress/Fishpig related posts

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, magento2, fishpig

I am currently trying to retrieve a list of related posts on the post article page (post single). I have created a new function within `/Block/Post/ListPost.php`

```
public function getRelatedPosts()
{
    $posts = $this->getPosts();

    die($this->getCategoryId());

    return $this->_postCollection;
}
```

However when I try and output `getCategoryId`, I get nothing. I'm also unsure how I apply a category filter to the post collection.

Can anyone advise here?

Comment: There's a stack exchange site just for magento [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MarceloStaudt Yes, there is, but having left my question on there unanswered for over a week, I thought I'd delete it and give it a shot here, where I've previously had much better luck.

Comment: @MarceloStaudt The developer of the module also seems to be more active on this site.

Comment: @wickywills Have you tried contacting the developer directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you have got the getCategoryId method from but this is not part of the ListPost block class so will not work. You cannot just invent methods like this.

You should check the block class for what methods are available. An easy way to do that without even loading the file is to add the following PHP to the class:

```
echo sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r(get_class_methods($this)));
exit;
```

You don't specify in what way the posts should be related but I'm guessing you want to get posts from the same category. One option to do this would be to load the primary category of the post and then get a post collection based on this. If you look in the Post class file, you will see the getParentTerm($taxonomy) method.

```
if ($category = $post->getParentTerm('category')) {
    $relatedPosts = $category->getPostCollection();

    // Remove the current post from the collection
    $relatedPosts->addFieldToFilter('ID', array('neq' => $post->getId()));
}
```

You should always look at the class file's you're working with. That is the beauty of open source. You can literally see what methods are available for each object and you can even see how they work.

Comment: Thanks for this - didn't know about using `addFieldToFilter` to remove the post!